# msbuild not compiling typescript in docker build, but works in azure pipeline

Tags: typescript, docker, msbuild

I'm in the process of attempting to containerize an asp.net .net framework web application.

I've mostly got it working. However I've found that for some reason it's not compiling my .ts files.

The build works correctly in an Azure DevOps Pipeline, but not in docker.

When I check the logs for the Azure DevOps build, I can see the following...

```
Processing resource file "My Project\Resources.resx" into "obj\Prod\Resources.resources".
PreComputeCompileTypeScriptWithTSConfig:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\3.1\tsc.exe   --project "D:\a\1\s\MyProject\tsconfig.json" --listEmittedFiles --listFiles --noEmit
CompileTypeScriptWithTSConfig:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\3.1\tsc.exe   --project "D:\a\1\s\MyProject\tsconfig.json" --listEmittedFiles
WebCompile:
...
```

However in my docker build, I'm seeing...

```
Processing resource file "My Project\Resources.resx" into "obj\Prod\Resources.resources".
WebCompile:
...
```

So it's obviously skipping the typescript bit.

I'm not sure what I'm supposed to do to make this run, as in Azure Devops it seemed to work automatically without me doing any extra configuration.

This is the msbuild command that Azure DevOps Pipeline is running...

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\amd64\msbuild.exe" "D:\a\1\s\MyProject.sln" /nologo /nr:false /dl:CentralLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba2196824\1.166.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll";"RootDetailId=|SolutionDir=D:\a\1\s"*ForwardingLogger,"D:\a\_tasks\MSBuild_c6c4c611-aa2e-4a33-b606-5eaba2196824\1.166.0\ps_modules\MSBuildHelpers\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.MSBuild.Logger.dll" /m /p:MvcBuildViews=true /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="D:\a\1\a\\" /p:platform="any cpu" /p:configuration="prod"
```

And this is what I'm using in my Dockerfile

```
msbuild ./MyProject.sln -target:MyProject -p:TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.7.2  -p:Configuration=prod -p:DeployIisAppPath='Default Web Site' -m -p:MvcBuildViews=true -p:DeployOnBuild=false -p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:OutDir=/artifacts /t:Package
```

Obviously the Azure DevOps command has a lot of extra stuff declared, but I'm not sure what specifically in this causes the typescript to build, or if it's even related to do with the msbuild options.

My Dockerfile uses the following base image...

```
mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.7.2
```

Just in case it's relevant, this is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "typeRoots": ["scripts/typings"],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "none"
  }
}
```

If there's any other information I need to include to make the question make sense, let me know. My project file is much too large to include, but if there are bits that would be relevant, I can add them.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, just in case it's helpful for others. I'm not sure if it's the best way to do it, but it works...

First, I added the following nuget package to the project...

```
Install-Package Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild -Version 3.9.2
```

When I tried to build the project though, it complained that it needed nodejs. I installed this in my Dockerfile like so...

```
ADD https://nodejs.org/dist/v12.18.0/node-v12.18.0-x64.msi ./node-v12.18.0-x64.msi

RUN msiexec /i node-v12.18.0-x64.msi AGREETOLICENSE=yes ADDLOCAL=ALL /qn
```

msbuild then ran the typescript correctly. One difference though, it ran the js version of the tsc compiler rather than the .exe, as Azure Devops does. It seems that the files have all compiled correctly though.